# In which field, minimal Weierstrass equation of elliptic curve can be defined?

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, local-field

For which fields can a, **minimal** Weierstrass equation of elliptic curve be defined?

If $K$ is a local field, valuation takes discrete value, so we can define a minimal Weierstrass equation.

But I heard if $K＝ \mathbb{Q}$, we can also define minimal Weierstrass equation.

For which fields can we define a **minimal** Weierstrass equation of elliptic curve?
(I guess we can do so for local fields and $\mathbb{Q}$ only, I can't define it on $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{F}_q$ or..)

Comment: You need valuations to get a good idea of "minimal". For any global field $K$ and a finite place $v$ of $K$ one can define a $v$-minimal model (via the completion $K_v$). If $K$ has trivial class group then there is a "global minimal Weierstrass equation" by taking a model minimal at all places $v$.

Comment: You've also been around long enough to be using MathJax. When typesetting blackboard letters use e.g., \mathbb{Q}

Comment: Then, over complex field, minimal weierstrass equation cannot be defined? (C is not local or global)

Comment: I would argue that minimal Weierstrass equations depend not only on the field $K$, but also on the choice of a Dedekind domain $A$ of which $K$ is the fraction field (and the theory is vacuous if $A = K$). So if $K = \mathbf{Q}$, we can take $A = \mathbf{Z}$, but we could also take $A = \mathbf{Z}[1/17]$ for instance. For $K = \mathbf{C}$ there are no sensible choices of $A$ except $\mathbf{C}$ itself and then the theory is vacuous (all elliptic curves are "minimal").